# GDAL Translate not working in R because something is missing in QGIS folder

Tags: qgis, gdal, r, gdal-translate

I get an error and I don't understand much. DO I have to install gdal in QGIS even if I'm using R? Is R using QGIS to run and translate jp2 sentinel files to tif?

> gdal_translate(ruta_bandas[2], "C:/Users/jpaol/Desktop/Converted/B02.tif")

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
'"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions\gdalinfo"' not found

Comment: does "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\apps\gdal\share\bash-completion\completions\gdalinfo" exist?

moreover I am wondering if that path points to the actual executable or just some commandline completion file

Comment: It does exist after checking by following path provided in my folder. But I'm not sure if it includes the command line I needed. I tried reinstalling gdal and qgis through OSgeo4w but it still didn't work. I'm just following the provided tutorial but I can't seem to figure out what error is for. I hope someone can help.